# The given sign-in provider is disabled for this firebase project. But its enabled

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

The given sign-in provider is disabled for this Firebase project. Enable it in the Firebase console, under the sign-in method tab of the Auth Section.

I have enabled it in firebase console

[Firebase Console Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3DAA.png)

The error on mobile

[Mobile Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPNJV.jpg)

> I tried updating my google service json.

> I tried disabling and reenabling the phone provider.

> I tried deleting the app from mobile and reinstall it.

But nothing changed same error

If want any file code ask me i will provide

Comment: Did you completed those additional configuration steps for Android?

Comment: If you are using same app for usage, try removing cache/data of your Android app.

Comment: I tried on many devices but same error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its work when i select "Start with 'Allow' to limit SMS usage to selected regions"

[image: Demo Image]

Comment: Thanks! It worked for me. It saved a lot of time. We contacted Google support, but they were not helpful with this.

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting this error `the given sign-in provider is disabled for this firebase project`.  I tried all possible methods but nothing worked anything for me. Then I downgraded `androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0` to `androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0` and luckily error resolved.