# The given sign-in provider is disabled for this Firebase project. Enable it in the Firebase console, under the sign-in method tab of the Auth section

Tags: android, flutter, dart, oauth-2.0, provider

i'm trying to solve this error but i can't find similar answers.I,m trying to auth by phone and i do all steps and activate the authentication provider in Firebase but still this error was shown.
please if there any solution for that. when i press login after putting the number this error shown.
error Message :The given sign-in provider is disabled for this Firebase project. Enable it in the Firebase console, under the sign-in method tab of the Auth section.

code :

```
 class AuthProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  bool _isSignedIn = false;
  bool get isSignedIn => _isSignedIn;
  bool _isLoading = false;
  bool get isLoading => _isLoading;
  String? _uid;
  String get uid => _uid!;
  UserModel? _userModel;
  UserModel get userModel => _userModel!;

  final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  final FirebaseFirestore _firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  final FirebaseStorage _firebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.instance;

  AuthProvider() {
    checkSign();
  }

  void checkSign() async {
    final SharedPreferences s = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    _isSignedIn = s.getBool("is_signedin") ?? false;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future setSignIn() async {
    final SharedPreferences s = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    s.setBool("is_signedin", true);
    _isSignedIn = true;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  // signin
  Future<void> signInWithPhone(BuildContext context, String phoneNumber) async {
    try {
      await _firebaseAuth.setSettings(appVerificationDisabledForTesting: true);
      await _firebaseAuth.verifyPhoneNumber(
          phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
          verificationCompleted:
              (PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) async {
            await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(phoneAuthCredential);
          },
          verificationFailed: (error) {
            throw Exception(error.message);
          },
          codeSent: (verificationId, forceResendingToken) {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => OtpScreen(verificationId: verificationId),
              ),
            );
          },
          codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (verificationId) {});
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      showSnackBar(context, e.message.toString());
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }

  // verify otp
  void verifyOtp({
    required BuildContext context,
    required String verificationId,
    required String userOtp,
    required Function onSuccess,
  }) async {
    _isLoading = true;
    notifyListeners();

    try {
      PhoneAuthCredential creds = PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
          verificationId: verificationId, smsCode: userOtp);

      User? user = (await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(creds)).user;

      if (user != null) {
        // carry our logic
        _uid = user.uid;
        onSuccess();
      }
      _isLoading = false;
      notifyListeners();
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      showSnackBar(context, e.message.toString());
      _isLoading = false;
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }

  // DATABASE OPERTAIONS
  Future<bool> checkExistingUser() async {
    DocumentSnapshot snapshot =
        await _firebaseFirestore.collection("users").doc(_uid).get();
    if (snapshot.exists) {
      print("USER EXISTS");
      return true;
    } else {
      print("NEW USER");
      return false;
    }
  }

  void saveUserDataToFirebase({
    required BuildContext context,
    required UserModel userModel,
    required File profilePic,
    required Function onSuccess,
  }) async {
    _isLoading = true;
    notifyListeners();
    try {
      // uploading image to firebase storage.
      await storeFileToStorage("profilePic/$_uid", profilePic).then((value) {
        userModel.profilePic = value;
        userModel.createdAt = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString();
        userModel.phoneNumber = _firebaseAuth.currentUser!.phoneNumber!;
        userModel.uid = _firebaseAuth.currentUser!.phoneNumber!;
      });
      _userModel = userModel;

      // uploading to database
      await _firebaseFirestore
          .collection("users")
          .doc(_uid)
          .set(userModel.toMap())
          .then((value) {
        onSuccess();
        _isLoading = false;
        notifyListeners();
      });
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      showSnackBar(context, e.message.toString());
      _isLoading = false;
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }

  Future<String> storeFileToStorage(String ref, File file) async {
    UploadTask uploadTask = _firebaseStorage.ref().child(ref).putFile(file);
    TaskSnapshot snapshot = await uploadTask;
    String downloadUrl = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
    return downloadUrl;
  }

  Future getDataFromFirestore() async {
    await _firebaseFirestore
        .collection("users")
        .doc(_firebaseAuth.currentUser!.uid)
        .get()
        .then((DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
      _userModel = UserModel(
        name: snapshot['name'],
        carType: snapshot['carType'],
        createdAt: snapshot['createdAt'],
        uid: snapshot['uid'],
        profilePic: snapshot['profilePic'],
        phoneNumber: snapshot['phoneNumber'],
      );
      _uid = userModel.uid;
    });
  }

  // STORING DATA LOCALLY
  Future saveUserDataToSP() async {
    SharedPreferences s = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await s.setString("user_model", jsonEncode(userModel.toMap()));
  }

  Future getDataFromSP() async {
    SharedPreferences s = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String data = s.getString("user_model") ?? '';
    _userModel = UserModel.fromMap(jsonDecode(data));
    _uid = _userModel!.uid;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future userSignOut() async {
    SharedPreferences s = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await _firebaseAuth.signOut();
    _isSignedIn = false;
    notifyListeners();
    s.clear();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this

1. Go to your firebase console
2. Go to Authentication > Settings
3. Select SMS region policy.
4. Select Allow and add your regions and Save

I was facing the same issue turns out there has been some kind of update and I followed these steps and it worked.

[image]

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/76163749/8721600